# jQuery Differences between methods on

Tags: jquery

What is difference between:

```
$("a.myclass").on("click", callback);
```

and

```
$(document).on("click", "a.myclass", callback);?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second method is used when `a.myclass` is added to the DOM dynamically (e.g. not present when the document is loaded). Ideally you want to use an element in the DOM that's closer than `document` to get the best performance<sup>*</sup>. Both bind to the click event on `a.myclass`.

Per the jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/) on `.on()` regarding the second format:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page.

<sup>* Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document tree can degrade performance. Each time the event occurs, jQuery must compare all selectors of all attached events of that type to every element in the path from the event target up to the top of the document. For best performance, attach delegated events at a document location as close as possible to the target elements. Avoid excessive use of document or document.body for delegated events on large documents.</sup>

Comment: So the second method is a sort of a `.live()` version of `.on()`?

Comment: @LittleBigBot - yes. In fact `.on()` replaced `.live()`.

Comment: Oh, I've been reading `.on()` as `.one()` this whole time. Pardon my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a.myclass").on("click", callback);
```

With this code, jQuery grabs all elements that match `a.myclass` and attaches the event handler to them.

```
$(document).on("click", "a.myclass", callback);
```

Here, jQuery grabs the `document` and attaches the event handler to click events that bubble up to it (that were originally trigger on elements matching `a.myclass`).

When you click `a.myclass`, the first will execute before the second, because the code has yet to 'bubble up' to the containing document.

The advantage with the second is that, as [j08691](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15229385/356541) says, elements matching that description that are added to the page after the script above executes (or come to match that description) will still trigger the callback.

The disadvantage is that if at some point you write the code

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

or

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    return false;
})
```

…then the second method will never fire. That's an edge case though, and you probably don't need to worry about it.